How to handle read replication lag when working with nextjs revalidatePath?
If we have a nextJS application which writes to a database in the server action and updates a counter, then calls revalidate after it. Since the read was done from a replica and there is some replication lag. the revalidatePath does not work. If i refresh the page right after a second. it works.
Example Scenario:

read is done from a elastic search index. (lets say getting highest upvoted answers first on stackoverflow.)
write is done to DB and upvotes are incremented on an answer in the db.
nextjs calls revalidate and elastic search is returning stale data.
an async job updates the elastic search answer index item with the updated upvotes.

I tried adding react useOptimistic hook to have local state updated instantly which work wonderfully well. Then I tried adding set-timeout on revalidate to delay it by 2-3 seconds. it looks like useOptimisitc goes back to stale value as soon as the action completes. this means an immediate revalidation is needed.

I think you have misunderstood the core concept of howrevalidatePath works together with useOptimistic. The goal is to serve immidiate user feedback and ensure another user is also able to see the like.
export default function LikeCounter({ likes, onCreate }: Props): JSX.Element {
  const [optLikes, addOptLikes] = useOptimistic(likes, (state, next) => {
    return [...state, next];
  });

  const onClick = useCallback(async () => {
    // optimistic update with a temporary id
    addOptLikes({ id: uuid() });
    // actually post the like to the api
    await onCreate(/* ... */);
    // revalidate the path so other users can see the new like
    revalidatePath(/* ... */);
  }, [onCreate]);

  return <button onClick={onClick}>{optLikes.length}</button>;
}

As you can see in the above example, I first update the optimistic state so the user gets immidiate feedback, then I create a new like and revalidate the path so other users can see the new like when the page gets visited the next time.
